# Using JS conditions in HTML to get a different hyperlink in birt

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, birt

Alright here's the situation. I want to add a hyperlink to a column in BIRT, but I also want to put a row at the end of the hyperlink.

To do that, normally I would just go like this.

`http://example.com/myfolders/myfiles/ + row["uuid"]`

in this screen. 
[image]

But, I want it so that if a certain row is null, there is no hyperlink attached to the row.

The Javascript would go like this.

```
if(row["uuid"]==null){
row["check_no"]
} else { <a href="http://example.com/myfolders/myfiles/<VALUE-OF>row["uuid"]</VALUE-OF>"><VALUE-OF>row["check_no"]</VALUE-OF></a>
```

This doesn't work because it has HTML in it. So when I try converting the whole thing to HTML, it goes like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    if(row["uuid"]===null){
    </script>
            <VALUE-OF>row["check_no"]</VALUE-OF>
    <script type="text/javascript">   } else {
    </script> '<a href="http://example.com/myfolders/myfiles/<VALUE-OF>row["uuid"]</VALUE-OF>">  <VALUE-OF>row["check_no"]</VALUE-OF></a>'

  <script type="text/javascript"> } </script>
```

This doesn't work. Is there another way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This javascript fragment does not work because it is mixing client-side and server-side expressions. Did you try to achieve the same just by testing null values in a dynamic URI expression such below:

```
 if (row["uuid"]!=null){  "http://example.com/myfolders/myfiles/" + row["uuid"] }
```

When uuid is null, this expression won't return any value and consequently hyperlinks are not created.

[image]

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of that. Maybe I'm too stressed, but I've tried everything but that. It helped, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try flipping it around. Instead of trying to get what is null, try getting what is not null.

```
if(row["uuid"] !== null){
"http://example.com/myfolders...." + row["uuid"]}
```